# dplyr::funs() soft deprecated - update to return variable name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, deprecated

Have spent a lot of time on this so hoping someone can advise. I have a piece of code that used funs(), which is soft deprecated and so have tried the alternative but cannot get it to work as expected.

**Old:**

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(x,y,z), 
                 .funs = funs(Comment = case_when(
  .%in% "YES") ~ deparse(substitute(.))))
```

This gives the three new variables: x_Comment, y_Comment & z_Comment - and will contain the relevant variable name ("x", "y" or "z") if the relevant variable contains "YES"

**Updated:**

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(x,y,z), 
                 .funs = list(Comment = ~case_when(
  .%in% "YES") ~ deparse(substitute(.))))
```

I have updated the code based on the warnings about funs() being soft deprecated however the above doesn't work. It gives the three new variables as expected: x_Comment, y_Comment & z_Comment - however if the relevant variable contains "YES" it give "." instead of the variable name.

Any solutions - preferably tidyverse very much so appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Heads up, `. %in% "YES"` is equivalent to `. == "YES"`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks! I use %in% when there are multiple options in a vector - had simplified the example to post here and just left it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
        x=c("Yes", "No",  "No"),
        y=c("No",  "Yes", "No"),
        z=c("No",  "No",  "Yes")
)

df %>% 
    mutate(
      across(everything(), 
      ~ifelse(.x == "Yes", cur_column(), ""), 
      .names="Comment_{col}")
    )
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  x     y     z     Comment_x Comment_y Comment_z
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Yes   No    No    "x"       ""        ""       
2 No    Yes   No    ""        "y"       ""       
3 No    No    Yes   ""        ""        "z"
```

Note that `mutate_at` is also deprecated.

Comment: Many thanks for such a quick reply! Looking at your output that is exactly what I want - however, I think my version of dplyr (0.8.5) is older than yours as it does not recognise across() or cur_column(). My R version is 3.6.1 (which I have no control over)- apologies should have specified initially! Also, thanks for the heads up regarding mutate_at() - I have not yet been getting warnings about this. Do you know when/what version it gets deprecated? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I'm on `dplyr` v1.0.0.  I _think_ that's the next version up from yours.  I'm pretty certain it's also when `across` and `cur_column` are introduced.  I'm guessing a `dplyr` upgrade is not an option for you?...

Comment: I will look into upgrading dplyr, and then will use your answer as it is exactly what I am looking for. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Chiming in to add that this solved a very similar problem I was having of needing to recode an array of survey responses  from character to numeric.  So thanks!